# how to use DPAD controls of remote in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-tv

Developing android Tv app. In Recycler view the the dpad controls of amazon fire stick are not navigating through recycler items. Can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306492/webview-on-amazon-fire-stick-not-responding-to-controller)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 its not relevant to my problem.